# Suggestions for a commuter bike with 20 inch wheels and suspension?

Tags: commuter, suspension, advice

Got my Raleigh Shopper stolen (thieves are so desperate nowadays), and looking for a similar replacement.      Could anyone suggest the best search query to search for similar bikes (Raleigh, BSA, Puch all made variations of it at some point)?

My main question, though, would be whether there is a similar-size or slightly (24 inch?) bigger bike that is also step-through, commuter-ready (comfortable seat standard, mudguards) and has suspension? Smaller than 20 inch is too small for me, so Moulton is out.

I could go with a suspension seat on some vintage shopper but wanted to check if there is something modern that fits the bill.

[image: Stock photo of a Shopper from https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/Y~oAAOSw~RNZmvjV/$_86.JPG]

Comment: 20 inches is small for a (non-folding) adult's commuter bike, unless you are unusually short.  There are probably hundreds of different 24" and perhaps 26" bikes that you would find suitable -- visit your local dealers.  Or Google `20-inch adult bike`.

Comment: Consider not owning a bike at all.   If you have a bike rental scheme in your area, consider joining and riding loan bikes.  If they get stolen, its not your problem.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - I'm guessing Raleigh Shopper is Raleigh Chopper? in which case, that is a children's bike.

Comment: @Batman - No, Google will show you that the Shopper is a 20" adult bike, styled like a foldie.

Comment: Googling suggests the Shopper is a raleigh 20 with a front basket.  As such, they're getting popular again, meaning more valuable and more of a target.

Comment: I have added a stock photo of a Shopper, showing the rear white plastic tray and the front plastic-coated wire basket.

Comment: I'm not sure why you rule out Moultons on the basis of wheel size. Everyone I've ever met riding one was average height or above (male). But they're expensive, even the license built versions

Comment: *thieves are so desperate nowadays*, really?  More desperate than 20, 40, or 60 years ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dahon mid range folders, and a lot of cheaper chinese clones, usually come with full guards. e.g. this: https://dahon.com/bikes/mariner-d8-2/
The steel frames are only a teensy bit heavier than aluminium, and last better - I have had both - steel would actually be my preference from Dahon.

If you are happy with 20" steering, then go folding - it's totally awesome, and sociable, to be able to fold your bike up, and easily throw it in the back of someones car for a ride home.

I am happy with the [Suntour seatpost](https://www.srsuntour.com/products/copy-of-sp12-ncx-seatpost?variant=27528514371), much better than the tubular type. not sure if you can get it to match the long fat seatpost of a folder though. (needs very regular oiling, and oiling before first use).

Can't help with the mini ape hangers though.